# saving data in database fails rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am novice in RoR and i am trying to save a new user into database as follow:
in the users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
@users= User.all
end
def new
@user= User.new
end
def create
@user =User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  redirect_to root_path
  flash[:notice]='you are a new user now!'
else
  render 'new'
  #flash[:notice]='oops!'
end

end

private
def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:l_name, :f_name, :email, :pseudo, :password_digest,    :password_confirmation)
 end
 end
```

my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
end
```

and my new.html.erb is like this:

```
<h1>Inscription</h1>
<%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :First_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Last_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :l_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pseudo %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :pseudo %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_digest %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and i just put this in the routes file :`root 'users#index'
  resources :users`

i aded the "gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'" in the gemfile

there 's no error shown just it render me to new page

this is the what shows the server

> Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-13 16:03:52 +0100
>   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
>   [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
>     Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (107.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 201ms (Views: 146.0ms | ActiveRecord: 49.0ms)
>   Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-13 16:04:09 +0100
>   Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SlNneso5r8eOLJ1fGcFI/aEr59jjPKcsrp0VgkXzupw=", "user"=>{"f_name"=>"tdg", "l_name"=>"gdfghf", "pseudo"=>"tdrytr", "email"=>"teryte", "password_digest"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
>      (1.0ms)  BEGIN
>      (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
>     Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 48.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that validations for the password were automatically added by using this the has_secure_password, and you are probably failing those validations on your local machine by trying to sign up with a simple password.

As a good practice please show the errors from your model if you keep the user on the **Create New User** page.

On your User view, if you don't have any error output code, do the following:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, to debug that always try to see if the output from this:

```
@user.save
```

Is true or not?

You could do something like this in the future:

```
saved = @user.save

Rails.logger.info("Was the user saved? #{saved}")
if saved

# redirect
else
  # etc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In here try to do this:-

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to root_path
  flash[:notice] = 'you are a new user now!'
else
  render 'new'
  flash[:notice] = @user.errors
end
```

You will see if there are any errors associated to your user object. I think some validations are not true for has_secure_password

Comment: thanks for responding me but that doesn't solve the problem, no error is shown